# Android keyboard overlapping inputs

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Using [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview) I have a basic example where I would like the keyboard to push the inputs upwards so it is not overlapping on Android. The inputs do not move when the keyboard is in focus. Any ideas?

The inputs stay in a fixed position, do I need to place everything in a scroll view?

**UPDATE: I use nested navigators, could a style on a parent component prevent this working?**

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <TextInput placeholder="input1" />
    <TextInput placeholder="input2" />
    <TextInput placeholder="input3" />
    <TextInput placeholder="input4" />
    <TextInput placeholder="input5" />
    <TextInput placeholder="input6" />
    <TextInput placeholder="input7" />
    <TextInput placeholder="input8" />
    <TextInput placeholder="input9" />
    <TextInput placeholder="input10" />
    <TextInput placeholder="input11" />
    <TextInput placeholder="input12" />
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change the `behavior` to  `height` for android as described on [keyboardavoidingview](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview)

```
import { KeyboardAvoidingView,  Platform  } from 'react-native';

<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
style={{ flex: 1 }} >
```